# Python: how to pass a reference to a function

Tags: python

IMO python is pass by value if the parameter is basic types, like number, boolean

```
func_a(bool_value):
    bool_value = True
```

Will not change the outside `bool_value`, right?

So my question is how can I make the `bool_value` change takes effect in the outside one(pass by reference?

Comment: Why do you want to? What's the context that prohibits you from simply returning a value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a list to enclose the inout variable:

```
def func(container):
    container[0] = True


container = [False]
func(container)
print container[0]
```

The call-by-value/call-by-reference misnomer is an old debate.  Python's semantics are more accurately described by CLU's call-by-sharing.  See Fredrik Lundh's write up of this for more detail:

- [Call By Object](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm)

Comment: if you are only using container for this purpose, there is no need to check `container[0]`. empty `container` for false and stick anything in it for true and then just test the container directly.

Comment: Sure, but I don't know the OP's use case from the question. I'm just showing one possible scenario; hopefully, the general method is clear enough.

Comment: A similar, but perhaps dirtier, method is to have the user pass `locals()` or `globals()`, and edit that dict directly.

Answer (score 3):

Python (always), like Java (mostly) passes arguments (and, in simple assignment, binds names) **by object reference**.  There is no concept of "pass by value", neither does any concept of "reference to a variables" -- only reference to a **value** (some express this by saying that Python doesn't **have** "variables"... it has **names**, which get bound to values -- and that is all that can ever happen).

Mutable objects can have mutating methods (some of which look like operators or even assignment, e.g `a.b = c` actually means `type(a).__setattr__(a, 'b', c)`, which calls a method  which may likely be a mutating ones).

But simple assignment to a barename (and argument passing, which is exactly the same as simple assignment to a barename) never has **anything at all** to do with any mutating methods.

Quite independently of the types involved, simple barename assignment (and, identically, argument passing) only ever binds or rebinds the specific name on the left of the `=`, never affecting any other name nor any object in any way whatsoever.  You're **very** mistaken if you believe that types have anything to do with the semantics of argument passing (or, identically, simple assignment to barenames).

Answer (score 2):

Unmutable types can't, but if you send a user-defined class instance, a list or a dictionary, you can change it and keep with only one object.

Like this:

```
def add1(my_list):
    my_list.append(1)

a = []
add1(a)
print a
```

But, if you do my_list = [1], you obtain a new instance, losing the original reference inside the function, that's why you can't just do "my_bool = False" and hope that outside of the function your variable get that False